Import 'django.urls' could not be resolved from source Pylance(Report Missing Module Source)
For configuring the global URLconfig on a project name, the codes "from django.urls import include, path" was required. When implemented on VScode, the warning is shown: 'django.urls could not be resolved from source--Pylance'. I followed exactly as per the tutorial in W3 school.
I am new to this area. I am unable to detect the mistake on my part despite several checking on the step by step procedure detailed in the tutorial

Hello, this could be an issue with interpreter selection. You can check if Django is installed in the environment of the interpreter you are currently choosing. Or use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+P to enter the command panel and type select interpreter to reselect the interpreter. Then download and install Django. See if that solves the problem?

This seems to be a common issue as raised here https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/207. You can read through the solutions and find the one that relates to your issue. I'll highlight some of them here;
First ensure that you are using an active virtual environment to manage your project. Ensure you have Django and other relevant packages installed therein.
Secondly, ensure you've installed the Python extension for Visual Studio Code.
Thirdly, ensure you're using the correct Python interpreter for your project and that it's added to path. A couple of persons reported that changing the python interpreter fixed this error. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django
